# Gradient with vector in log?

Tags: vectors, logarithms, gradient-descent

I am relatively new to taking derivatives involving vectors and matrices.

I am wondering if there are any special rules when calculating the derivative of a log when there are vectors in the logarithm?

For example I want to calculate the gradient of this function

$$f(\theta) = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{p=1}^P ln(1+e^{-\theta^T z_p} ) $$ where $ z_i \in R^{Nx1}$ and $\theta \in R^{Nx1}$

My thoughts would be that since $ z_i \in R^{Nx1}$ and $\theta^T \in R^{1xN} \therefore \theta^T z_i \in R^{1x1}$, I can treat the exponent as a scalar, since the inner product is a scalar and simply compute the derivative

$$\nabla f(\theta) = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{p=1}^P \frac{(-e^{-\theta^T z_p}) (-\theta^T z_p)}{1+-e^{-\theta^T z_p}} $$

However I don't know if there was some special way I was supposed to treat $z_p$ since it was a vector in this. Is this the correct way to calculate this?

Edit: I'm also not sure if the above derivation is correct even if it was to be treated as a scalar

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are taking derivatives w.r.t. $\theta = (\theta_1,..,\theta_p)$, hence, just use the chain rule for every $\theta_j$, $j=1,..,p$. I.e.,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} g(\theta ^ T z_p) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} g( \sum_{j=1}^p \theta_j z_j)   
= g'( \sum_{j=1}^p \theta_j z_j) z_j
$$
where, in your case $g: \mathbb{R^p} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $g(\theta) = \ln (1 + \exp\{- \theta^Tz_p\} )$, so
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}g(\theta) = \frac{ - \exp\{- \theta^Tz_p\}z_j}{1 + \exp\{- \theta^Tz_p\}}
$$